# Change CSS Style with AJAX and without reloading

Tags: javascript, php, css, ajax

Is it possible to change the color of an CSS element after something happened in the Server?

In my program I click a button, and after this a PHP programs starts. This program changes a value in the server (value of a GPIO port of a Raspberry Pi).

Is there a possibility that i can change a CSS attribute with PHP after the side is loaded? If I try AJAX it has no impact because the site is already loaded, and the output has no effect on the site.

```
<div id="output">  
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    var gpio_status = '0';
  </script>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var php_output = document.getElementById("output");
var request;

function gpio_out(gpio_nr) {
  request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("post", "gpio_out.php", true);
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  request.send("daten=" + gpio_nr);
  request.onreadystatechange = request_status;

}

function request_status() {
  if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
    php_output.innerHTML = request.responseText;
  }
}
</script>
```

Content of the AJAX file:

```
  $gpio_status = shell_exec("cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio" . $gpio_nr . "/value");

  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "var gpio_status = '$gpio_status';";
  echo "</script>";
```

At the End i want the JS variable "gpio_status". But it has got always the same value which is the value i gave it at the beginning: 0. If I colsole.log() the variable I always get 0. But my other Code works fine.

Comment: should be easily done within an ajax callback by either toggling a class or inline style using javascript. Overall question details are far too vague though. Take some time to read [ask] and [Question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) then update question with proper details and code

Comment: `If I try AJAX it has no impact because the site is already loaded, and the output has no effect on the site` - you're doing it wrong, show the code

Comment: Can you please check my code?

Comment: Does `$gpio_nr` ever change? Are your status values dependent on the value of `$gpio_nr`?

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language, this means (for all intents and purposes) that you hit it with a request and spits back a response and dies. Yes, you can change the CSS style of an element if you are willing to reload the page and are willing to have PHP control some state in the backend.

> If I try AJAX it has no impact because the site is already loaded, and the output has no effect on the site.

You must be AJAXing wrong then, as AJAX was invented to solve problems exactly like your question.

Comment: But I think the JS Interpreter is not loading the code i load from AJAX, bacause the site is already loaded.